# Create device with extra fields tags of device twin in Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is it possible to define a property in tags of deviceTwin while creating a device in Azure IoT Hub? or it is needed to create device first, then get and update the deviceTwin. It seems 'Registry.create' (from node sdk) does not accept such an option. What is I want to achieve is following

```
`...
const device ={
    deviceId: '1',
    tags: {
        location: 'London'
    }
}
registry.create(device, callback)
...`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to define a property in the tags of Device Twin while creating a device by using `Registry` in node. In fact, the `create` method in Registry class is calling the PUT REST API to [create or update device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createorupdatedevice). The device information should be referred to the Request Body, it does not accept properties items in request body.

However, there is a way to work around. You can use [Bulk Create Or Update Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/bulkcreateorupdatedevices) to create a new device with tags and [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/bulkcreateorupdatedevices#propertycontainer).

For example, post the request body as following:

```
[
    {"Id":"7ADF1F8E-0208-49B7-B62A-021323EF1B55","tags":{"location": "London"},"properties":{"desired":{"Temperature":30}},"Status":"enable","importMode":"create"},
    {"Id":"F2805601-1F4D-459F-9D8F-E2F7D3638EF5","tags":{"location": "New York"},"properties":{"desired":{"Temperature":31}},"Status":"enable","importMode":"create"},
    {"Id":"D0447599-5B2D-4EDB-A809-29643CC7E30E","tags":{"location": "Paris"},"properties":{"desired":{"Temperature":32}},"Status":"enable","importMode":"create"}
]
```

After that, you will find the tags and desired property in device twin.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Strange that they don't accept tags when using PUT

Comment: Just updating as the links do not exist anymore. The create and update device does not take tags as a parameter in the rest endpoint: [create or update device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/createorupdateidentity)  if you look at the update device twin rest endpoint it takes the tags as a parameter [Update Device Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/updatetwin) You can see in the nodejs link for update device twin that it takes a patch object nodejs devicetwin update documentation

Comment: [nodejs devicetwin update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iothub/registry?view=azure-node-latest#updateTwin_string__any__string_) looked at the BulkRegistry but it needs a IotHubGatewayService which there is no examples of how to create it and is different from the normal registry. The normal registry uses connection strings and SAS tokens.   [Bulks Registry for devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iothub/bulkregistry?view=azure-node-latest#updateRegistry_ExportImportDevice____RequestOptionsBase__ServiceCallback_BulkRegistryOperationResult__)